# IntelliJ - How to see the full javadoc of an element (annotation, method, class .. etc) that belongs to a maven dependency?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, javadoc

IntelliJ only shows a very brief description and not the full javadoc of elements included in maven dependencies, how can I see the full javadoc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to force IntelliJ to download the documentation associated with the maven dependencies as this is not enabled by default. To do so, follow the next steps:

1. Open the maven toolbar
2. Open the settings in the toolbar
   [image]
3. Maven Settings -> maven -> Importing
4. Check the Documentation checkbox
   [image]
5. Click OK

This will ensure the documentation is automatically downloaded for all modules that will be added to this project.

If you have already opened/created a maven module before doing this, then do the above to solve this issue for the next modules. For the current module:

1. Right click on the module in the Project Explorer
2. Maven -> Download Documentation
   [image]

Please note that this works only for the current project. I'm not sure if there's a way to apply this globally across all IntelliJ projects.